# Angualr 7 SSR - Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'service-worker.js'

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-service-worker

I have created Angular 7 project and added Server Side Rendering and Service worker.
Command to Run - `npm run build:ssr` && `npm run serve:ssr`
After above command project run on `localhost:4000` and on hitting it in browser it gives below error.

```
Error - ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'service-worker.js'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'service-worker.js'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (/home/am-n1/Documents/Documents/angular7boilerplate/dist/server.js:134788:16)
    ...
```

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: For whoever closed this issue: it is not a duplicate, it's a completely different problem, related to ssr, that tends to throw the same error message erroneously. Anyway, did you solve the issue?